# Is this code thread safe with spring PostConstruct

Tags: multithreading, spring-boot, postconstruct

I have done some tests on these two classes. Could someone please help to determine if these two classes are threadsafe? Could someone help to identify if not using concurrentHashMap, but use HashMap would it cause any concurrent issue. How can I make it more threadsafe?  What is the best approach to testing it with concurrent testing?

I tested it with Hashmap only and it works fine. However, my scale of test is around 20 req/s for 2 mins. 
Can anyone suggest if I should increase the req rate and try again or can point somewhere that must require fix.

@Component
public class TestLonggersImpl
    implements TestSLongger {

```
@Autowired
YamlReader yamlReader;

@Autowired
TestSCatalog gSCatalog;

@Autowired
ApplicationContext applicationContext;

private static HashMap<String, TestLonggerImpl> gImplHashMap = new HashMap<>();

private static final Longger LONGER = LonggerFactory.getLongger(AbstractSLongger.class);

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    final String[] sts = yamlReader.getTestStreamNames();
    for (String st : sts) {
        System.out.println(st);
        LONGER.info(st);
    }
    HashMap<String, BSCatalog> statsCatalogHashMap = gSCatalog.getCatalogHashMap();
    for (Map.Entry<String, BSCatalog> entry : statsCatalogHashMap.entrySet()) {

        BSCatalog bCatalog = statsCatalogHashMap.get(entry.getKey());
        //Issue on creating the basicCategory
        SProperties sProperties = yamlReader.getTestMap().get(entry.getKey());
        Category category = new BasicCategory(sProperties.getSDefinitions(),
            bCatalog.getVersion(),
            bCatalog.getDescription(), new HashSet<>());

        final int version = statsCatalogHashMap.get(entry.getKey()).getVersion();
        getTestImplHashMap().put(entry.getKey(),
            applicationContext.getBean(TestLonggerImpl.class, category,
                entry.getKey(),
                version));
    }
}

@Override
public void logMessage(String st, String message) {
    if (getTestImplHashMap() != null && getTestImplHashMap().get(st) != null) {
        getTestImplHashMap().get(st).log(message);
    }
}

@VisibleForTesting
static HashMap<String, TestLonggerImpl> getTestImplHashMap() {
    return gImplHashMap;
}
```

}

*** 2nd class

@Component
public class GStatsCatalog {

```
@Autowired
YamlReader yamlReader;

private static HashMap<String, BStatsCatalog> stCatalogHashMap = new HashMap<>();

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    String[] streams = yamlReader.getGSNames();

    for (String stream : streams) {
        BStatsCatalog bCatalog = new BStatsCatalog();
        SProperties streamProperties = yamlReader.getGMap().get(stream);
        bCatalog.setSName(stream);
        int version = VERSION;
        try {
            version = Integer.parseInt(streamProperties.getVersion());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        bCatalog.setVersion(version);
        bCatalog.setDescription(streamProperties.getDescription());
        stCatalogHashMap.put(stream, bCatalog);
    }
}

public static HashMap<String, BStatsCatalog> getCatalogHashMap() {
    return stCatalogHashMap;
}

public void setYamlReader(YamlReader yamlReader) {
    this.yamlReader = yamlReader;
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

I think the methods under @postconstruct are threadsafe. It only runs once after the bean created in the whole lifecircle of the bean.